# VSCode debugger launch.json config for Bun + next.js

Tags: visual-studio-code, next.js, vscode-debugger, bun

[This page](https://bun.sh/guides/runtime/vscode-debugger) describes how to configure VSCode to debug with [Bun](https://bun.sh/).

[This page](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/debugging#debugging-with-vs-code) describes how to configure VSCode to debug a next.js app.

But what's the launch.json config that combines both, so I can debug my next.js app running on Bun?

Answer (score -1):

Check first if this page "[Bun for Visual Studio Code](https://github.com/oven-sh/bun/tree/47651f321ae5eb82686da5d759e9b1b5b12340ad/packages/bun-vscode)" can offer a starting point with their `launch.json`

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "bun",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Debug Bun",

      // The path to a JavaScript or TypeScript file to run.
      "program": "${file}",

      // The arguments to pass to the program, if any.
      "args": [],

      // The working directory of the program.
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",

      // The environment variables to pass to the program.
      "env": {},

      // If the environment variables should not be inherited from the parent process.
      "strictEnv": false,

      // If the program should be run in watch mode.
      // This is equivalent to passing `--watch` to the `bun` executable.
      // You can also set this to "hot" to enable hot reloading using `--hot`.
      "watchMode": false,

      // If the debugger should stop on the first line of the program.
      "stopOnEntry": false,

      // If the debugger should be disabled. (for example, breakpoints will not be hit)
      "noDebug": false,

      // The path to the `bun` executable, defaults to your `PATH` environment variable.
      "runtime": "bun",

      // The arguments to pass to the `bun` executable, if any.
      // Unlike `args`, these are passed to the executable itself, not the program.
      "runtimeArgs": [],
    },
    {
      "type": "bun",
      "request": "attach",
      "name": "Attach to Bun",

      // The URL of the WebSocket inspector to attach to.
      // This value can be retrieved by using `bun --inspect`.
      "url": "ws://localhost:6499/",
    }
  ]
}
```

---

For instance, you can try and add a script in your `package.json` for running your Next.js application with Bun.
Let's say your entry file for the Next.js application is `server.js`:

```json
"scripts": {
  "dev": "bun server.js",
  ...
}
```

A possible combined `launch.json` could look like this:

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Next.js + Bun: debug server-side",
      "type": "node-terminal",
      "request": "launch",
      "command": "npm run dev",
      "runtime": "bun",
      "runtimeArgs": [],
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/server.js",
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
    },
    {
      "name": "Next.js: debug client-side",
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "url": "http://localhost:3000"
    },
    {
      "name": "Next.js + Bun: debug full stack",
      "type": "node-terminal",
      "request": "launch",
      "command": "npm run dev",
      "runtime": "bun",
      "runtimeArgs": [],
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/server.js",
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "serverReadyAction": {
        "pattern": "- Local:.+(https?://.+)",
        "uriFormat": "%s",
        "action": "debugWithChrome"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "bun",
      "request": "attach",
      "name": "Attach to Bun",
      "url": "ws://localhost:6499/"
    }
  ]
}
```